# Mysql Table Insert Performance

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, doctrine, innodb

I have table with following schema: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YacoL.png

Its MySQL, running on InnoDB, on basic Digital Ocean host ( 512 MB, 1 CPU ). I am using **PHP/Doctrine**, and in my code, i do something like

```
for( $i = 0; $i < 5000; ++$i ) {
    $row = findRowInTable();
    if (! $row ) {
        insertNewRow();
    }
}
$em->flush();
```

It's slow, it takes something like 20s when table is empty, and 50s when table have 5000 rows.

How can I optimize it? I will be adding at most 5K rows, but I need to get this process under 120 secs even if table will be 200K rows long

Comment: If you want performances, don't use doctrine.

Comment: You're going to need a bigger boat.

Comment: and get more ram. another cpu'd be nice too. Plus, we don't know if you're not opening/closing db connection in that same loop and/or querying with db-related stuff in there.

Comment: @JayBlanchard The Titanic sank a long time ago ;-) Time for a Speed boat! with 2x 454's and 8 barrels each or better yet, a [blower!](https://c1.staticflickr.com/7/6114/6271342844_1a2c82e9db_b.jpg) on 2x 426 HEMIs.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Doctrine, but look for a way to do `INSERT IGNORE` instead of looking for the row first, and find a way to bulk inserts.

Comment: If you want speed, don't use PHP for it, have mysql handle it

Comment: [Mine has more muscle...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38773414/mysql-table-insert-performance#comment64918447_38773414) @Drew MOPAR muscle that is ;)

Comment: Also take a look at MySQL's INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax (more useful than INSERT IGNORE in some cases)

Comment: Guys, thanks for comments. 
I've rewritten findRowInTable() ( pure PDO now  ) -5s :/, Inserts aren't much better with IGNORE ( and i need notify user if there are duplicities btw ), Doctrine DO bulk inserts ( flush() method ).

Comment: This is way too little code to figure out what's going on. There's usually nothing wrong with an ORM like Doctrine but if you use them incorrectly they may do an extraordinary amount of work to try and achieve what you're asking of them.

Comment: Please show us the SQL that was generated.  Generally, SQL runs _much_ faster if you batch actions in single statements, not perform loops.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to find the rows that are not in database, outside the loop, try to find the rows with a single query, and let php iterate.

```
$rowsARR = findRowsNotInTable();
for( $i = 0; $i < sizeof($rowsARR); ++$i ) {
       insertTheRow($rowsARR[i]);
}
$em->flush();
```